# How Does Instagram's GET/tags/<tag>/media/recent Pagination Actually Work?

Tags: instagram-api

I'm trying to use the [Real-time Photo Updates](http://instagram.com/developer/realtime/) API to get all pictures with a specific tag as they come in.  Since updates from this API really only tell you *that* new content exists (but not *what* it is), I am querying for recent media with my tag whenever I get the notification that something has changed.

The problem I am having is that I'm constantly getting duplicate media returned by that query.  The documentation says this API does pagination, but I can't get it to work at all.

The documentation [here](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/tags/#get_tags_media_recent) says to use `min_id` and `max_id` in your query string to control pagination, however it says:

- MIN_ID - Return media before this min_id.
- MAX_ID - Return media after this max_id.

This seems backwards (normally min should return items above the minimum and max should return items below the maximum so that when you specify both you get a bounded range).

The actual JSON I get back from my queries includes a pagination object like this:

```
"pagination":  {
    "next_max_tag_id": "1387272337517",
    "deprecation_warning": "next_max_id and min_id are deprecated for this endpoint; use min_tag_id and max_tag_id instead",
    "next_max_id": "1387272337517",
    "next_min_id": "1387272345517",
    "min_tag_id": "1387272345517",
    "next_url": "https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/cats/media/recent?access_token=xxx&max_tag_id=1387272337517"
}
```

The parameter specified in the `next_url` property is `max_tag_id`, not `max_id` like the documentation says.

There is also a deprecation warning that states that `next_max_id` and `min_id` are deprecated, but since there are properties in the pagination object with names like that, I don't know whether the query parameters or the object properties the ones that are deprecated..

I would think it means the properties, because the query string never used a parameter of `next_max_id`, but then the deprecation message says to use `min_tag_id` and `max_tag_id` and there is no `max_tag_id` property on the pagination object (just a `next_max_tag_id`).

Regardless of all of this conflicting documentation, it doesn't seem to matter what I pass in my query string - I continue to get repeat media in subsequent queries.  Can someone help me make sense of this API?  All I really want is to get tagged media that is new since my last query.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To get the newest set of grams for a particular tag, use this:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/latergram/media/recent?access_token=TOKEN
```

From that response, you can get newer grams from the same tag by taking the `min_tag_id` from the response (under pagination) and build a url like so:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/latergram/media/recent?access_token=TOKEN&min_tag_id=1387332980547
```

Or you can get the next (older) set of grams by using the next_url parameter from the original response (also under pagination), which looks like:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/latergram/media/recent?access_token=TOKEN&max_tag_id=1387332905573
```

Make sure your subsequent queries (for new grams of a particular tag) are using the `min_tag_id` returned by the latest response. I did a few tests and didn't see duplicates, however I was using #latergram and that one has a high volume of posts

Comment: Switching to #latergram showed me my problem.  I was using #selfie (which is like a fire hose), so I couldn't clearly see that I was issuing multiple requests with the same min_id.

Comment: More `POST`s were coming in from Instagram while I was still waiting for a response from the last `GET` command I issued.  Since I can't update `min_id` until the `GET` comes back, all of those `POST`s were triggering duplicate `GET` requests.

Comment: @zachallia how would you get around the issue of having a very high - volume tag update? I am faced with a similar problem: I do not want to miss any photos that were tagged, but waiting on the `GET` request to come back would mean using the same min-id multiple times.

Comment: @zachallia you said `Make sure your subsequent queries (for new grams of a particular tag) are using the min_tag_id returned by the latest response` what do you mean by LATEST. Is this the last one I did, or the one with the most recent grams? Also, should I keep the `min_tag_id` along with the `max_tag_id` on additional calls in this new scope?

Comment: where can i get the `min_tag_id` ?

Comment: @mori, Hello, I'm interested in the same thing. Have you found the solution to that? I've tried adding them random values and I get `min_id must not be a media id`. Same goes for the `max_tag_id`. There is no documentation about this on their website.

Answer (score 7):

@zachallia has answered spot on, but I figure it can't hurt with a sketch:

As the [Instagram API says](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/tags/#get_tags_media_recent):

`MIN_TAG_ID  Return media before this min_tag_id.
MAX_TAG_ID  Return media after this max_tag_id.`

This is counterintuitive, with a slightly nutty flavor. But still, it is possible to make sense of it.

The `/tags/MYTAG/media/recent` endpoint will give you grams, ordered by how newly they where tagged with MYTAG. You'll not get all grams, of course, just up to the limit set by Instagram:

```
|yesteryear ------------------ <---- LIMIT ----> now|
```

If you use `min_tag_id` like so `/tags/MYTAG/media/recent?min_tag_id=X` you'll get grams from X and before (aka older):

```
|yesteryear ------- <---- LIMIT ---> min ------- now|
```

If you use `max_tag_id` like so `/tags/MYTAG/media/recent?max_tag_id=Y` you'll get grams from Y and after (aka newer):

```
|yesteryear ------- max <---- LIMIT ---> ------- now|
```

That's how "max" gets to signify "newer" and "min" gets to signify "older".

Comment: Hello. How should I use `min_tag_id` and `max_tag_id`? What values should they have in the request? I tried giving them random values like `23423423`, but I get an error like this: `min_id must not be a media id`

Comment: @Ionut min/max_tag_id must be actual media ids (an ID to an existing Instagram media post). So yeah, you could use `23423423`, provided it is an actual media id.