# No pagination information using instagram API

Tags: json, url, pagination, instagram, instagram-api

I used this `URL` to get the recent media about specific `tag` like `cats` using `Instagram API`. the `URL` is like this:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/cats/media/recent?access_token=*****
```

Unfortunately, there is no data and I got the below `warning` in `pagination`:

```
{"pagination":{"deprecation_warning":"next_max_id and min_id are deprecated for this endpoint; use min_tag_id and max_tag_id instead"},"meta":{"code":200},"data":[]}
```

how can I get `min_tag_id` or `min_tag_id`? why there is no `data`?

Comment: Simplying passing them to your query. You can see `next_url` to follow, and check http://stackoverflow.com/a/20641829/2151050 for explanation on how both parameters works

Comment: thanks @AdamAzad! yes I have tested it before and gotten the same warning.

Comment: Getting the warning is totally normal. It's a **deprecation warning** meaning it keeps reminding you not to use the deprecated parameters. You can ignore it :). Instagram API will remove it in body response when they **fully deprecate them**

Comment: @AdamAzad the problem is I do not get any data even for popular tags like cats.

Comment: Hmmm, for me, this [URL](https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/cats/media/recent?access_token=2253563781.137bf98.bd1c3693d2b84f80a7ab8d661f641437) worked fine

Comment: @AdamAzad Getting same error... Do I have to make the instagram client live or I can test it in sandbox mode?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I assume you created your client for this request after Nov. 17 2015. Instagram made some changes to their API, see [here](https://instagram.com/developer/).

> Apps created on or after Nov 17, 2015 will start in Sandbox Mode and function on newly updated API rate-limits and behaviors.

Your app/client is probably in sandbox mode and thus it has limited behavior. It's written down in the docs, [section API behaviour](https://www.instagram.com/developer/sandbox/):

> Data is restricted to sandbox users and the 20 most recent media from each sandbox user.

[...]

> As another example, let's consider an endpoint that returns a list of media: /tags/{tag-name}/media/recent. The response returned by this endpoint will contain only media with the given tag, as expected. But instead of returning media from any public Instagram user, it will return only media that belongs to your sandbox users, restricted to the last 20 for each user.

If you create a "cat" tag with your sandbox user, you should see it. Once your app has switched to live, you should see all public available "cat" tags.

Regarding the deprecated warnings, they are normal as they inform apps that used the "old way" about breaking changes. In your case they can be ignored.