# Instagram API Retrieve Hash Media - next_max_id and min_id are deprecated for this endpoint; use min_tag_id and max_tag_id instead

Tags: php, curl, instagram-api, hashtag

I want to fetch instagram hashtag media like [iconosquare](http://iconosquare.com/tag/coffee).

So I'm using [Cosenary PHP Api](http://cosenary.github.io/Instagram-PHP-API/) to kickstart my instagram project.

After I authenticate/access the url with the `$instagram->getLoginUrl()`

Then the page will redirect me to my callback url with `?code` parameters.

In my callback url's php files, I use the code and get my access_token :

```
$data  = $instagram->getOAuthToken($_GET['code']);
$access_token = $data->access_token;
```

So with the access_token, am trying to get *coffee* media tag files

```
$url   = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/coffee/media/recent?access_token={$access_token}";
```

and access it using Php [CURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16700960/how-to-use-curl-to-get-json-data-and-decode-the-data) method,

but the data return to me as

```
array(3) {
  ["pagination"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["deprecation_warning"]=>
    string(94) "next_max_id and min_id are deprecated for this endpoint; use min_tag_id and max_tag_id instead"
  }
  ["meta"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["code"]=>
    int(200)
  }
  ["data"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

May I know what is min_tag_id and max_tag_id ?
I added the parameter follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625173/how-does-instagrams-get-tags-tag-media-recent-pagination-actually-work) but still achieve the same result.

I can't search any documentation on [instagram developer website](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I just found out my Instagram Application is in sandbox mode.
So it doesn't return me any data ( it because my instagram doesn't have #coffee hash tag, try to search your own ( or any sandbox user's ) instagram's hashtag instead...

If the Application's review status is approved, then it will retrieve public hashtag instead of sandbox user's hashtag.

Instagram did have stated on [here](https://www.instagram.com/developer/review/) that there is some limitation when an application is in sandbox mode.