# Instagram hashtag search api does not return any data but status is 200

Tags: php, instagram, instagram-api, hashtag

I've created ap app on instagram and it is in sandbox mode bydefault . Then i've validated an access_token according to api requirements then i've started calling new api and here's the response i am getting

```
stdClass Object
(
[pagination] => stdClass Object
    (
        [deprecation_warning] => next_max_id and min_id are deprecated for this endpoint; use min_tag_id and max_tag_id instead
    )

[meta] => stdClass Object
    (
        [code] => 200
    )

[data] => Array
    (
    )

)
```

The response code 200 is the code for success but why am i getting empty data and that warning ? It must show atleast 20 posts.

`[deprecation_warning] => next_max_id and min_id are deprecated for this endpoint; use min_tag_id and max_tag_id instead`

How to achieve this? your help will be highly appriciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Instagram API Retrieve Hash Media - next\_max\_id and min\_id are deprecated for this endpoint; use min\_tag\_id and max\_tag\_id instead](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34721009/instagram-api-retrieve-hash-media-next-max-id-and-min-id-are-deprecated-for-th)

Comment: Ok as suggested in your reference link i've created a new sandbox account and authorized access token also and posted an image with same hashtag that i've posted on my sandbox account but it fetches only my posts not others . Why is it so ? @tomudding

Comment: this is because your Instagram App is in sandbox mode, until the App its review status is approved, it will retrieve sandbox user his/her hashtag instead of public hashtag. Check the [sandbox developer documentation](https://www.instagram.com/developer/sandbox/) for more information.