# empty response from Instagram API

Tags: node.js, instagram-api

I'm trying this code :
I'm using nodejs, express as back-end and request as package.

```
router.get('/',function(req, res, next){
    request({
        url: 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/alibaba/media/recent?access_token=xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        method: 'GET',

    },function(err,status,body){
        var tags =JSON.parse(body);
        res.json(tags);
    });
});
```

but response was this :

```
{"pagination":{"deprecation_warning":"next_max_id and min_id are deprecated for this endpoint; use min_tag_id and max_tag_id instead"},"meta":{"code":200},"data":[]}
```

I create new client but error was the same

what can I do ?

Comment: Did you read this [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625173/how-does-instagrams-get-tags-tag-media-recent-pagination-actually-work)?

Comment: i think u are in sandbox mode, it will return only media from sandbox authorized users