# Instagram Tags API sometimes missing pagination min_tag_id from when content returned is less than requested

Tags: php, instagram, instagram-api

I'm using the Instagram Tags API with a min_tag_id, to get content that is newer than the last time I called. I'm getting back an array with content, but the pagination details are lacking a new min_tag_id.

An example might be calling 
`https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/stackoverflow/media/recent`

Saving the `min_tag_id` on my db

Calling again a day later to 
`https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/stackoverflow/media/recent?min_tag_id=<the_one_I_saved>`
, getting back content, but no `min_tag_id` making it difficult to keep iterating from the last place I stopped.

This doesn't happen all the time, which make me think there's either something wrong with `min_tag_id` handling over on their side, or it has some sort of behavior that isn't documented (expire?)

UPDATE: I actually figured out the `this doesn't happen all the time` part. It only happens when the `count` parameter I'm sending to the API request more content that currently available. In those cases Instagram is only giving `max_tag_id` and no `min_tag_id`, but I see no sense in that according to how these two tags seem to react ([How Does Instagram's GET/tags/<tag>/media/recent Pagination Actually Work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625173/how-does-instagrams-get-tags-tag-media-recent-pagination-actually-work)). I can see why max_tag_id isn't relevant in such a case, because if you just got back less results than you requested, there's no way someone can go back in time and add posts that were posted before these posts. However, it's obvious that can happen in the future. What gives?

Comment: Usually min_tag_id should be included. If not, why dont you try using max_tag_id. If my memory serves right, max_tag_id becomes the min_tag_id for next set of images.

Comment: @AjitKumarSingh I want to save this point in time, and sample again at a later time, only getting photos that were added after my last sampling sync. AFAIK max_tag_id will iterate backwards in time, and min_tag_id will iterate forward in time. Can you clarify if I might have a wrong understanding of them?

Comment: @AjitKumarSingh Also - when you say `usually`, what do you mean? When would you expect it to not be present?

Comment: Consider you have 3 pagination of data. 20images each for each pagination. So for first pagination, min_tag_id is 1 and max_tag_id is 20. For 2nd min_tag_id is 20 and max is 40. for 3rd min is 40 and max is 60. Now consider the situation, your 4th pagination has only 4 images. so min will be. 61 and max will be 64.

Comment: Now whats happening in your case is that the next day, suppose only 3 more images has been added. but your previous min was 60. So if you use previous min, you will get max_tag_id as 67. But your previous min still remains the same. You need to update your previous min with max_tag_id, for the last pagination for the array of data. What you can do is check if min_tag_id exits in the current array. If it exits, use that. Else find a way to use max_tag_id. Build a logic for that.

Comment: @AjitKumarSingh In your example, did you mean 1 is the oldest picture and 60 is the newest? If so, I'm actually under the impression that in your example the first page will have min_tag_id 20, and max_tag_id 1. Max_tag_id helps me move further back in time, and get posts with a id that is smaller than max_tag_id, and min_tag_id helps me come back tomorrow to find newer posts. Are we on the same page?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115723/discussion-between-noam-and-ajit-kumar-singh).