# Get all media use instagram api in sandbox

Tags: api, instagram, instagram-api

I have a app use instagram api. In sandbox I want to all media but I get only 20 media. first, I call api

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}/media/recent/?access_token={access-token}
```

I get the first 20 medias. Next, `max_id`  will be id of the last record. But result return empty.

my code

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}/media/recent/?access_token={access-token}&max_id={max-id}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its sandbox limit:

> To help you develop and test your app, the users and media available
>   in Sandbox mode are real Instagram data (i.e. what is normally visible
>   in the Instagram app), but with the following conditions:
>
> - Apps in sandbox are restricted to 10 users
> - Data is restricted to the 10 users and **the 20 most recent media** from each of those users
> - Reduced API rate limits

https://www.instagram.com/developer/sandbox/

Answer (score 0):

You can get the next set by using the next_url parameter from the original response like this.

```
if (r.pagination.next_max_id){
            $('.instagram').attr('data-instagramnext', r.pagination.next_max_id);
        }
```

You can also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20641829/4323328) comment for getting more information.